# gitignore doesn't ignore files in a subdirectory

Tags: git, autoconf

So, I want git to ignore some files in a sub-directory inside a git repository.

The project directory structure layout is basically as follows:

```
GIT_ROOT
---project1
------src
```

I want git to ignore certain files in `GIT_ROOT/project1`.  I do this by creating a `.gitignore` file and ignoring things like `Makefile` or other autoconf-generated fluff.  However, `autoconf` also creates Makefiles in sub-directories, so a Makefile will be generated in `GIT_ROOT/project1/src` as well.  Naturally, I want to ignore all Makefiles in `GIT_ROOT/project` AND `GIT_ROOT/project/src`.

I thought I could do this by adding the following to the `.gitignore` file in `GIT_ROOT/project1`:

```
**/Makefile
**/Makefile.in
```

My understanding is that this should instruct git to ignore *any* Makefiles which appear in `GIT_ROOT/project1` - or any Makefiles which appear in sub-directories, such as `GIT_ROOT/project1/src`.  However, when I actually commit and push to a remote master, git *only* ignores Makefiles in `GIT_ROOT/project1` - but it doesn't ignore any Makefiles in deeper directories.

Do I need to include a `.gitignore` file in every sub-directory?  If not, why is the `.gitignore` file in `GIT_ROOT/project1` *not* applying to Makefiles in `GIT_ROOT/project1/src`?

Comment: `**/Makefile` and `**/Makefile.in` work for me.  What version of Git are you using?  I'm currently using version 2.0.1.  Also, you can do `/project1/**/Makefile` and `/project1/**/Makefile.in` if you want to only ignore them under `project1`.  It may be that they are not being ignored because they're already under version control (.gitignore does not apply to versioned files).

Answer (score 3):

You simply can add to your `.gitignore` file in `GIT_ROOT/project1`:

```
Makefile
Makefile.in
```

No need for '`*`' wildcards.
That will be applied to `project1` and any sub-folder.
You can check that with a [`git check-ignore -v -- project1/xxx/Makefile`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore).

If they aren't ignored, that means they are already versioned: a git rm --cached can remove them from the index.